# What is the expected value of $a^T X b$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, random, random-matrices

Let $a, b\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and $X$ a random matrix with shape $n\times n$. Let $\Bbb{E}[X]=C$. Find $\Bbb{E}[a^T Xb]$.
I did just that:
$$
\Bbb{E}[a^TXb]=a^T\Bbb{E}[X]\ b=a^TCb
$$
but I don't know if I did it right.
How to prove or disprove this?

Comment: Expected value is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a^\intercal X b = \sum a_i b_j x_{i,j},$ so linearity of expectation shows that $$E(a^\intercal X b) = \sum a_i b_j E(x_{i,j}) = \sum a_i b_j c_{i,j} = a^\intercal C b.$$ Same calculation would apply for matrices $E(AXB) = AE(X)B.$

Comment: @SilvioM Where exactly is this using/claiming a countable sample space? This is a perfectly fine proof for general $n\times n$-matrix-valued random variables.

Comment: @SilvioM None of the steps assume that $X$ has a counting density. The summation is over the entries of $a$ and $b$, which are finite vectors by assumption.

Comment: @SmallDeviation ok then I have read wrong, my fault. It's better if I delete the comments for avoiding confusion of the reader

Answer (score 2):

$a$ and $b$ are constants, the randomness here is only on $X$ and the thesis thus follows from the linearity of the expected value.

If you want to see it by computations, assume you have a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Then we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[a^T X b] = \int_{\Omega} a^T X b \ dP = a^T \left(\int_{\Omega}  X  \ dP\right) b = a^T \mathbb{E}[X] b \ ,$$
where the last step is a consequence of the linearity of the integral.

Comment: You are skipping the crux of the proof. The obvious question is now why does the integral can switch between matrix products?

Comment: @WilliamM. the question was asking another thing actually, not the linearity of the integral, which should be already known if you are doing probability.

Comment: Linearity of the integral often means that $X \mapsto \int\limits_\Omega X dP$ is a linear function, namely (1) $\int\limits_\Omega (X_1 + a X_2) dP = \int\limits_\Omega X_1 dP + a \int\limits_\Omega X_2 dP.$ Turns out that this version of linearity implies rather readily (see my answer) that (2) $\int\limits_\Omega u(X) dP = u\left( \int\limits_\Omega X dP \right)$ for $X$ a random matrix and $u$ a linear function on the vector space of matrices. It is not always obvious that (1) implies (2), and as far as I know, all integrals are defined with (1) in mind....

Comment: ...For example, when one works with Bochner integral, a form of (2) still follows from (1) but to prove it, it is necessary to appeal to some form of the Hahn-Banach extension theorem.